# How to transform a number to two decimal in an ngModel?

Tags: angular

I have an input with a quantity, I would like to add two decimal in the `ngModel`

[image]

```
<div class="col-6">
   <input type="text" id="qte" name="qte" [(ngModel)]="qte ">
</div>
```

I have a pipe `| pipeFormatNum:'1.2-2'`, but I don't know how to use it in the ngModel?

**edit**

```
  qte: number;
  changementBeneficiaire: string = '';
  dest: string = '';


 
  private getSolde(): void {
    this.service.getSolde(this.internalTransactionWatchtoConfirm.titre.svm).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {

        if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
            this.qte = res.TRANS[0]["SOLDE"];
            console.log(this.qte);
        }
    });
  }

  onInputChange(event: string) {
    this.qte = Number.parseFloat(event).toFixed(2);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this

```
<div class="col-6">
   <input type="text" id="qte" name="qte" [ngModel]="qte" (ngModelChange)="onInputChange($event)">
</div>
```

Then in your .ts file go with this

```
onInputChange(event: string) {
  this.qte = Number.parseFloat(event).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: I don't think event is going to be a number, isn't it going to be a string? I guess you could change the code to `this.qte = (+event).toFixed(2) || event`.

Comment: Ok, you can do this `this.qte = Number.parseFloat(event).toFixed(2);` and pass a string in the method. Im going to change the answer

Comment: @Arthur Pérez, Merci, mais si j'essaye votre code j'ai un message d'erreur `TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'` ??

Comment: Check now, I edit the answer to recieve a string

Comment: @Andrei Tătar, thank you for your help, In the TS, the variable `qte` is a number.
I tried your code, I also got an error message: `TS2322: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Comment: Note that if your input type is text, then you have to bind to a string variable on your .ts.

Comment: @Arthur Pérez, the variable `qte` is a number in the TS. I have an error message `TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.` ???

Comment: You could change the type of the variable in your .ts to string, since you are using a text input in your template. Then if you want to work with this qte variable in some other part as a Number simply do `let qteNum = Number(this.qte);`